# Solving recurrence equation $T(n)=T(n^{2/3})+17$

Tags: recurrence-relation

How can the following recurrence equation be solved by one of three main ways:

$$T(n)=T(n^{2/3})+17$$

I have tried solving it by the iteration way. However it does not work for me since I can't find the equation with $i$, i.e the generic equation.

Comment: Have you tried applying any of the methods listed [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers)?

Comment: The answer will be proportional to the number of times that you have to raise a number to the power $2/3$ until it gets below an arbitrary constant. I'm sure you can work that out on your own.

Comment: I’d recommend using a spreadsheet to find Say T(1000); that should give you some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this pretty easily with a change of variables here. Let $n = 2^{(3/2)^k}$ we then can rewrite $T(n)$ as:
$$S(k) = S(k - 1) + 17$$
We have $S(k) = O(k)$. Then converting $k$ back to $n$ we have:
$$k = \log_{3/2} \log_2 n$$
Thus, $T(n) = O(\log \log n)$.

Comment: Is it also $T(n) = \theta (\log_{3/2} \log_2 n)$?

Answer (score 3):

This post answers [the original version of the question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/revisions/105634/1), where the recurrence relation is

$$T(n)=T\left(\frac{n^2}{3}\right)+17$$

---

The recurrence relation is somewhat unconventional. Here is an outline to solve it.

Suppose $n\ge 6$. Let $n=3\cdot2^{2^{m}}$, where $m=\log_2(\log_2\frac n3)\ge0$.

$$\begin{align}
T(n)
&=T\left(3\cdot2^{2^{m}}\right)
 =T\left(\sqrt{3\cdot\left(3\cdot2^{2^{m}}\right)}\right)-17\\
&=T\left(3\cdot2^{2^{m-1}}\right)-17
 =T\left(\sqrt{3\cdot3\left(\cdot2^{2^{m-1}}\right)}\right)-2\cdot17\\
&=T\left(3\cdot2^{2^{m-2}}\right)-2\cdot17
 =T\left(\sqrt{3\cdot\left(3\cdot2^{2^{m-2}}\right)}\right)-3\cdot17\\
&=\cdots\\
&=T\left(3\cdot2^{2^{m-\lceil m\rceil}}\ \right)-\lceil m \rceil\cdot 17
\end{align}$$

Since $-1\lt m-\lceil m\rceil\le0$, $3\sqrt2\lt3\cdot2^{2^{m-\lceil m\rceil}}\le6.$ So 
$T(n)\sim -17\log_2(\log_2 n)$ when $n$ goes to $\infty$.

---

Here are two related exercises.

**Exercise 1**. What is the recurrence relation for function $S$ such that $S(n)=T(3n)$?

**Exercise 2**. What is the asymptotic behavior of $T(n)$ if $n$ goes to 3 from above, assuming $T$ is continuous?

Comment: Who edit the question, change the whole exercise. It should be n^(2/3).

Comment: I am afraid that you wrote it as n^2/3, as shown in [the first version](https://cs.stackexchange.com/revisions/105634/1), which was changed it to n^(2/3) more than 14 hours later.

Comment: Question clearly was posted as T(n squared divided by 3), changed to T(n followed by some weird stuff) by OP then changed to T(cube root of n squared). Original is the most interesting one :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another similar answer to Apass.Jack on the ["original"](https://cs.stackexchange.com/revisions/105634/1) question.

First flip the function around:

$$T\left(\frac{n^2}{3}\right) = T(n) - 17$$

Convert it to an intelligible form by a change of variables where $m = \tfrac{n^2}{3}$:

$$T(m) = T(\sqrt{3m}) - 17$$

Try another change of variables where $m = 3 \cdot 2^{2^\omega}$. We get:

$$T(\omega) = T(\omega - 1) - 17$$

Thus $T(\omega) = -17\omega$. Now we work backwards:

$$\begin{align*}
T(\omega) & = -17 \omega\\
T(m) & = -17 \log_2 \log_2 (m / 3)\\
T(n^2 / 3) & = -17 \log_2 \log_2 (n^2 / 9)\\
T(n) & = -17 \log_2 \log_2 (n / 3)\\
\end{align*}$$

This assumes a base case of $T(\omega = 1) = -17$ or the following other assumed base cases:

$$\begin{align*}
T(\omega = 1) &= -17\\
T(m = 6) & = -17\\
T(n = 6) & = -17
\end{align*}$$